# Filter by multiple resourceId's

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Is there a way to query by multiple `resourceId`'s using the .Net library?

For instance, usually I query for a single feed entry by `resourceId` like this:

```
DocumentsListQuery query = new DocumentsListQuery();
query.Uri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri, doc.ResourceId));
DocumentsFeed feed = service.Query(query);
```

I'm wondering if there's some way to query for multiple documents by their `resourceId`'s in a single query, instead of just fetching the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

A single RESTful query can only return a single element or a feed, so there's no way to query by multiple `resourceId`'s.

An alternative might be to specify a search query that restricts your results to the elements you want, but such search criteria only exist if your files have something in common that differentiates them from the other documents.

The documentation for search query in the Documents List API is available at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#searching_for_documents_and_files, but I'd also recommend you to take a look at the newer [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) and at how it manages search:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#searching_for_documents_and_files